# ASP.NET Azure MySQL code first migrations: Table 'xxx' already exists

Tags: mysql, azure, entity-framework-migrations

I have this frustrating problem when trying to enable code migrations to create DB schema on azure MySql DB i got the:

```
[DbConfigurationType(typeof(MySqlEFConfiguration))]
```

specified to my data context and also

```
        var configuration = new App.Migrations.Configuration();
        var migrator = new DbMigrator(configuration);
        migrator.Update();
```

but a simple Table that contains only ID property and a String doesnt seem to work on Azure, it says
Table 'xxx' already exists, and when it doesnt it gives another error saying 
Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes

whats wrong with the MySQL and Code First schema generation?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Issue is likely...

1. Your Entity Code
2. Your Seed Code
3. Table probably does already exist

I would recommend opening the Visual Studio 2015 SQL Server Object explorer and running a few queries on the tables in question or just see if those tables exist and what data is in them.

I also do not like code first migrations, for these sorts of reasons.  I would recommend following this tutorial series.

https://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/Have-you-tried-turning-it-off-and-on-again/Creating-a-Database-Project-for-Artificial-Intelligence

https://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/Have-you-tried-turning-it-off-and-on-again/Deploying-Database-Projects-to-SQL-Azure

https://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/raw-tech/AI-Part-3-Entity-Framework-and-Unit-Tests